# service endpoint error

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

i have written a simple wp7 application. it uses wcf service and files to store user provided data.
i could successfully run the app without errors but i am getting a runtime err: 
**"An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' could not be located because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name"** 
the acf contains the following endpoint configurations set

```
 <services>
      <service name="WcfDataWallet.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="WcfDataWallet.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

can someone help me please

Answer (score 3):

I just had this same issue.  I only added 1 Service Reference to my project in VS 2010, however, I noticed that in web.config 2 endpoints were added

I just commented out the second endpoint as I'm fairly certain that I don't need it.

Thus before

```
<endpoint address="http://web_services.u.aco/ServicesLocations/1_1/LocationsService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILocationsService"
    contract="LocationService.ILocationsService" name="WSHttpBinding_ILocationsService" />
  <endpoint address="http://web_services.u.aco/ServicesLocations/1_1/LocationsService.svc/basic"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILocationsService"
    contract="LocationService.ILocationsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILocationsService" />
```

Changed to:

```
<endpoint address="http://web_services.u.aco/ServicesLocations/1_1/LocationsService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILocationsService"
    contract="LocationService.ILocationsService" name="WSHttpBinding_ILocationsService" />
  <!--<endpoint address="http://web_services.u.aco/ServicesLocations/1_1/LocationsService.svc/basic"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILocationsService"
    contract="LocationService.ILocationsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILocationsService" />-->
```

Works Now!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MyClientProxy proxy = new MyClientProxy("endpoint name"); eg EndPointNameXXX
```

Where "endpoint name" should be pointing to one of your endpoints in client config file.

```
<endpoint address="http://[SERVER]/Service"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingConfig"
                contract="IXXXX.YYYY" name="EndPointNameXXX" />
```